# Хранение данных в xml

Tags: android-studio, xml, android-xml

Такая ситуация:
Есть 300 объектов, их кол-во увеличивается каждый год на 5-15
Каждый объект имеет 20-60 параметров
Объекты разделены на группы 20-40 в группе
Вопрос: правильно ли будет хранить все это в одном xml файле, примерно 3мб будет получено. Или лучше разбить: 1-xml - названия объектов, т.е. индекс со ссылками на файлы объектов, и для каждого объекта создать свой однотипный xml, примерно 3-5кб.

Как лучше хранить такую схему:

```
Группа подразделений (1-n): номер группы, цвет
   ...
   |
   Подразделение (1-n): имя, номер группы
      ...
      |
      Отдел 1: имя, номер
      Некие параметры 1 отдела: 1-20 типа параметр-значение
      Параметры 1 отдела: имя значения, 4 параметра
      Контакты 1 отдела: имя, местный, город, коммент
      Файлы эл.схем отдела 1 pdf
      Файл план отдела pdf
      Некие изображения 1-10 шт
      Отдел 2...
      ...
      Отдел 4...
```

Comment: а что на счет бд? почему именно xml решили использовать?

Comment: Лучше все хранить в одном файле, будь то БД или какая-то другая структура. На заре персоналок было многофайловые БД. Но было неудобно. То файл индекса потеряется (сотрут), то разбегутся файлы и перестанут соответствовать друг другу например при нештатном выключении питания системы.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Суть в чём:если держать всё в одном файле,то с каждым вызовом он будет прогружаться полностью.Если же потратить время и разбить всё по файлам, то обращение к ним будет быстрее.Но вопрос в том,критична ли прогрузка этих трёх мегабайт.А вообще как было сказано лучше бд или хранить в файле json

Comment: Спасибо, теперь я задумался о json, правда приложение пока будет независимым, т.е. без клиент-сервера.

Comment: А можно ли в json хранить и другие данные, типа изображения или файлы? Или хранить только ссылки на файлы

Comment: @Андрей - json, как и xml - текстовые форматы. Поэтому для хранения в них изображений или файлов их придётся переводить в текст. Например, в base64. PS: так сделано в электронных книгах fb2.